# Can someone please clarify the language function of the expression typed in bold below

Tags: grammar

A couple of teachers have got different opinions about the function in one of the lines in below given conversation.

> Principal : We all are going to visit the museum tomorrow.
>   Student : That's very nice sir, can we bring our cell phones?
>   Principal : No,  NOBODY SHOULD BRING THE CELL PHONES.

Enough discussion has taken place about the usage of the modal SHOULD but we couldn't come to a conclusion whether the line ...NOBODY SHOULD BRING THE CELL PHONE.... means, advice, order, direction, or suggestion.plz help me what is the function of this line.

Answer (score 1):

Context. The senior teacher is giving instructions to the students.

Should is generally used to give advice. But, if a school principal tells you "you should not do it", then it is a command. It may be phrased as advice, but the context indicates that it can't be disobeyed without consequences. So it is a command.

On the other hand, if one teacher were to say to another.

> You shouldn't take your cell phone either.

That is advice, because the teachers are equal.

(minor point: In your example, don't say "the cell phones", instead say "their cell phone")

Comment: Is "his cell phone" also correct in this case?

Comment: Yes, but could be considered insulting if the students are not all male.